# Creating complete graph of nodes of different types

Tags: omnet++

Suppose I have the following network:

```
network Network {
    submodules:
        nodeA: nodeA;
        nodeB: nodeB;
        nodeC: nodeC;
        ....
}
```

Suppose along with `nodeA`, `nodeB`, and `nodeC`, there are a variable amount of module types to be included in the submodules section of the network. Suppose that there could be a thousand more. What would be the most efficient way to create a complete graph out of these nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark all your modules with a specific property in NED (i.e. something like the @NetworkNode property in INET) and then you can use the `cTopology::extractByProperty()` call to extract a topology of those marked modules.

For example, `topo.extractByProperty("node");` would extract all modules that contain the `@node` property, like the following one:

```
module X {
    @node;
}
```